# Real-world consequences of misusing Redux reducers?

Tags: javascript, redux

I've inherited a Redux codebase, and I found a bit of the code that violates Redux's cardinal rule: no side effects in reducers.

Specifically, there's a `tracking` reducer and it looks something like this:

```
function tracking(state = {}, action) {
  function sendEvent(event, data) {
    // API call here to send a tracking event
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case TRACK_FRIEND_REQUEST:
      sendEvent('track-friend-request', action.payload);
      return state;

    case TRACK_LINK_CLICK:
      sendEvent('link-click', action.payload);
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is obviously wrong; the state is meaningless and it only exists for its side-effect. The correct solution (IMO) would be to create a `tracking` middleware that listens for actions with a `meta` property, and attach `meta` properties to the *actual* events, instead of creating these specialized track events.

Surprisingly, though, I can't find any real consequences of using it this way, and I'm having a hard time justifying why it's worth the effort to fix it (there are a lot of these tracked events, so it would be a fair bit of work).

The only potential problem I see is that, when using the devtools, events would get re-sent whenever you toggle the action. We already ignore tracking actions in dev mode, though, so this isn't a concern.

Are there other reasons that this code would cause real-world problems that I'm not aware of?

Comment: The only problem I can imagine is that if new developers jump on this code-base, they might implement some state changing functionality depending on the response of your api call. As you pointed out, this is just a misuse of redux. Middleware would be the way to go.

Comment: Agreed, I think I'll add some comments "denouncing" this reducer to guard against that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you're dead-on.  The primary issue would be with debugging while using the Redux DevTools.  Flipping back and forth between previously dispatched actions would cause those actions to be dispatched again through the reducers, and thus re-trigger this behavior.

And yes, the "correct" place for this sort of thing would be a middleware.

Comment: I'm actually surprised to hear that there aren't more significant ramifications! It's such a code smell, but I guess this is one of the few cases where this only creates _academic_ problems. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah. At a technical level, Redux just calls your root reducer and stores the result. The focus on "pure functions" is a combination of DevTools / time travel debugging, ensuring that React-Redux updates appropriately, testability, and general usefulness of Functional Programming concepts.